# Tokbox archived video is letterbox (black border around video)

Tags: php, jquery, ffmpeg, archive, tokbox

I have archiving setup to save my tokbox publisher streams straight to an AWS S3 Bucket; But the final saved archive.mp4 is appearing letter-boxed / has black borders around the stream video rather than stretching the video to fit the whole frame. Is there any way to change this? It is completely on the tokbox end and I also have the fit-mode for the publisher set to "contain" although changing it to cover doesn't change anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this post, the `fitmode` property on the Publisher doesn't affect the layout of the archive. TokBox has a separate feature that allows you to do this. You can find information about it here: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/layout-control.html